# Web request to a3rd party and receive the response

Tags: vb.net

I create a web page and i kept tht page in liver server. the page link in someurl/inboundmessage.aspx. in the page load i wrote the code request.querystring("Sender"). but this value is always returning blank

I am using a 3rd party software to get the parameter . ther 3rd party software rule 
www.somelink/inbound.aspx?Sender"34345"receipient= "SDFASDF",datetime="dfsdf"

What needs to be done in the vb.net coding to retrieve the parameter from them

This is my code in vb.net web application . Is any body can give the solution how should i retrieve the message

```
if Request.QueryString("sender") <> "" And Request.QueryString("receipent") <> "" And
        Request.QueryString("content") <> "" And Request.QueryString("datetime") <> "" Then

            sw.WriteLine("Message from Dynmark " + Request.QueryString("sender") + ", " +
                  Request.QueryString("recipient") + ",  " + Request.QueryString("content") +
            ",  " + Request.QueryString("datetime"))
            sw.WriteLine("Message Added")
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a response variable (HttpWebResponse), then you can go just say Response = Request.getResponse. Obviously you will have to send in the request first by Request.send.

Comment: can you please provide me the steps how i should proceed i am new to this vb.net development